# Add new vertex if edge attribute is greater than some value

Tags: r, igraph

I want to insert a new vertex if an edge attribute is greater than some value and then split the edge attribute, for example:

```
library(igraph)
m <- matrix(c(1:5,2:6), nc = 2, byrow = F)
g <- graph_from_edgelist(m)
g <- set_edge_attr(g, name = "dists", value = c(5,8,10, 15, 7))
plot(g, edge.arrow.size = 0)
```

[image]

I want to add a new vertex if the edge attribute "dists" is > 10, for this graph that is between the 3rd and 4th vertices as the edge attribute is 15.

```
E(g)$dists
[1]  5  8 10 15  7

# psuedo code of what I want to do
for(i in E(g)) {
  if (E(g)$dists[i] > 10) {
    #add new node and split the edge weights
  }
}
```

what the result would look like

```
m2 <- matrix(c(1:6,2:7), nc = 2, byrow = F)
g2 <- graph_from_edgelist(m2)
g2 <- set_edge_attr(g2, name = "dists", value = c(10,10,10, 7.5, 7.5, 10))
plot(g2, edge.arrow.size = 0)
```

[image]

A new vertex has been added between the old 3rd and 4th vertices and the edge attribute that was 15 has been split to 7.5 and 7.5, across the new edges.

```
E(g2)$dists
[1] 10.0 10.0 10.0  7.5  7.5 10.0
```

This a toy example, in my data there are 100's of vertices and 10's of new vertices will be getting added, so I can't do it manually. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is to write a little function to do this, since this entails a few different steps to properly index the edges and vertices. Using a `while` loop, the function runs until all the edges with `dists > 10` are split.

First, the data for reproduction:

```r
library(igraph)

m <- matrix(c(1:5,2:6), nc = 2, byrow = F)
g <- graph_from_edgelist(m)
g <- set_edge_attr(g, name = "dists", value = c(5,8,10, 15, 7))
```

And the function with comments explaining:

```r
split_edges <- function(g, thres, edge_name = "dists") {

  # Set the condition
  while (sum(edge_attr(g, edge_name) > thres) > 0) {

    # Get the edge id for first edge >= threshold
    eid <- which(E(g)$dists > thres)[1]

    # get vertex ids for that edge
    idx <- c(ends(g, eid))

    # Add the new vertex
    g <- add_vertices(g, 1)

    # get the id of the new vertex
    new_vx <- as_ids(V(g)[length(V(g))])

    # Add the edges
    g <- add_edges(g, c(new_vx, idx[1], new_vx, idx[2]))

    # Add the edge attributes
    g <- set_edge_attr(g, 
                       edge_name, 
                       index = E(g)[(length(E(g)) - 1):length(E(g))],
                       value = c(edge_attr(g, edge_name, index = eid) / 2,
                                 edge_attr(g, edge_name, index = eid) / 2))

    # delete the original edge 
    g <- delete_edges(g, eid)
  }

  return(g)

}
```

Testing it out:

```r
g2 <- split_edges(g, 10, "dists")
E(g2)$dists
#> [1]  5.0  8.0 10.0  7.0  7.5  7.5
plot(g2, edge.arrow.size = 0, edge.label = E(g2)$dists)
```

[image]

I quickly tested this on a larger graph as well:

```r
set.seed(1981)
g <- sample_gnp(100, 0.1)
E(g)$dists <- floor(runif(length(E(g)), min = 0, max = 15)) 
sum(E(g)$dists > 10)
#> [1] 132

g2 <- split_edges(g, 10, "dists")
sum(E(g2)$dists > 10)
#> [1] 0
vcount(g2)
#> [1] 232
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>